# Table cell's image gets disappear when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is how my table view looks.
[image: TableView]

here is my code
This is what happens when I scroll down
[image: Image with bug]
**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

{
    NSMutableArray *items ;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *items ;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize items;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [items addObject:@"bla bla bla"];
    [items addObject:@"rikifhdif bla bla"];
    [items addObject:@"bla sdfkndskfnlk bla"];
    [items addObject:@"sdf,nsdmf bla bla"];
    [items addObject:@"sdjkfhksd bla bla"];
    [items addObject:@"dkfhkusd bla bla"];
    [items addObject:@"bla sdfjknskdjf bla"];
    [items addObject:@"kiidrfjifig jjojdjfgdfgjjdjsjkhksidfl"];
    [items addObject:@"mksjdhf ysdgjg bla"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
#pragma tableview logic
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 6;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return @"Title0";
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return @"Title1";
    }
    else if(section == 2)
    {
        return @"Title2";
    }
    if(section == 3)
    {
        return @"Title3";
    }
    else if(section == 4)
    {
        return @"Title4";
    }
    else 
    {
        return @"Title5";
    }
    }
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (section==1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section==2) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (section==3) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (section==4) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section==5) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:

            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];

            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];

            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
    //}
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [items release], items = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Just want to show image for the first row of every section. The output is ok at the time of loading but when I scroll the view the first image gets disappear.
How Do I fix this issue?? Any help would be appreciated. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't obvious in the code that you're hiding them?

Comment: YEs That is what I want to achieve. just want to show image for the first row.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I don't know y but some of the text content was missing thats Y this confusion occurred. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I'm not sure for what reason I got 3 down votes?? If some can inform me would be nice as I don't want to repeat that mistakes.Thanks

Comment: I downvoted b/c of your original question was confusing, but it's now fine as you have edited it. Dunno about the others, maybe they downvoted when they saw the original one...

Comment: Downvoted for using excessive `if`'s, `cases` and string literals in your code. Also, you have way too much redundancy. You repeat the code in your `case` 5 times. I would advise using an `NSArray` for your section header titles, and `indexPath` contains a section as well as a row, so you don't need your switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already set images hide for your Index-Path.row like:-

For example Section One you set  `if (indexPath.row==1) {  [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];}` as same as `if (indexPath.row==2)` that's why your section one display only First 0th index row image Appear other not displaying.

```
case 0:

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
    }
    else{
        [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
    }
```

**just replace your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code with my bellow `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];   //uniq identifire for each section with it's row

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
           cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];

            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }

            break;
        case 1:
             cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];

            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 2:

              cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];

           if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 3:

             cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];

           if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 4:

             cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];
            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;
        case 5:

             cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.jpg"];

            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
            }
            else {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
    //}
}
```

create CellIdentifier like this:-

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];   //uniq identifire for each section with it's row
```

Comment: But that is what I want to achieve as I said I just want to show image for the first row and not for the rest of the rows

Comment: For your kind info sir index start with 0 not with 1 and if you want to achive this then what happen with appear or not Appear...?

Comment: Yes I know that every array starts from index 0. But I want to show image for index 0 and want to hide rest of the images.

Comment: Do you mean that just need to set image for the 0 and don't need to bother about the rest of the indexes .. is it???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32209/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-mayurcm)

Comment: check now i put cellforrowIndex code as you need impliment it hope now your issue will be solve

Answer (score 3):

Your images disappear as you scroll down because `UITableView` reuses its cells. Say, for row 1 of the first section, you asked for the cell, and made its image hidden

```
case 0:
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
    }
```

Now later when you scroll down, `UITableView` is smart enought to know that the cell is no longer used (as it's no longer visible on the screen), and it **reuse** the cell for new rows appearing down the view. And since you have made the image hidden, it's hidden. The key here is that no new cells are created, only old cells are reused, and their states haven't changed.

To fix this, simply add the case for `row == 0`:

```
case 0:
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
    }
    else ...
```

I suggest a clearer syntax:

```
case 0:
    cell.imageView.hidden = indexPath.row != 0;
```

Or, if you want images only for *all* the first row of *all* sections:

```
cell.imageView.hidden = indexPath.row != 0 // No need of case expression
```

Comment: for first row of each section, `indexPath.row` is always `0`, regardless of the section

Comment: i just talkin about section specify case like case 0: 1 etc

Comment: ... and in each case, you put `cell.imageView.hidden = indexPath.row != 0`, and all cases have the same logic, and we don't need `case` anymore?

Comment: yes thats' true i thought  u talking about section specify case that's why i saying :)

Comment: I didn't know what you were talking about anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

table view cell load the cell when appear, simply you add this code all case 0: 10 case 5:

```
if (indexPath.row==0) {
                [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];  
            }
```

my sugession you reduce your code like this for all case:

```
if (indexPath.row==0) {
            [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
        }
        else {
            [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it by making the below change. But I'm not sure is it the right thing to do or not.

```
//if(cell == nil) 
//{


    //}
```

What I did is comment out the cell condition that check whether the cell is nil.